# number 622.08E6 interpretation in C

Tags: c, floating-point, exponentiation, number-literal

I recently came across a C code (working by the way) where I found

```
freq_xtal = ((622.08E6 * vcxo_reg_val->hiv * vcxo_reg_val->n1)/(temp_rfreq));
```

From my intuition it seems that `622.08E6` should mean `622.08 x 10^6`. Is this assumption correct?

I tried googling for a similar example where E notation is used in a C program. Surprisingly couldn't find any result

Comment: You may find the grammar in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961467/why-isnt-0f-treated-as-a-floating-point-literal-in-c/3965845#3965845) interesting.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a scientific notation and why is double printed in scientific notation in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026121/what-is-a-scientific-notation-and-why-is-double-printed-in-scientific-notation-i)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the constant E do in the c language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54293135/what-does-the-constant-e-do-in-the-c-language)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.  It works just like an old-school scientific calculator.

In this case, it looks like you're dealing with a 622.08MHz signal and a VCOX on a PLL?