# Why doesn't my code work when replacing 622.08E6 with 622080000?

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, precision

I recently came across a C code (working by the way) where I found

```
freq_xtal = ((622.08E6 * vcxo_reg_val->hiv * vcxo_reg_val->n1)/(temp_rfreq));
```

From my intuition it seems that 622.08E6 should mean 622.08 x 10<sup>6</sup>. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781570/number-622-08e6-interpretation-in-c) this assumption is correct.

So I tried replacing 622.08e6 with

```
uint32_t default_freq = 622080000;
```

For some reason this doesn't seem to work

Any thoughts or suggestions appreciated

Comment: What does not work, do you receive and error are your values wrong?

Comment: The chip I am trying to program does not behave as expected with just this one change.

Comment: what's your expectation and what's the actual result?

Comment: We don't have enough information, some code would probably help, it is suspicious that you are using a integer value in place of a floating literal.

Answer (score 6):

The problem you are having (and I'm speculating here because I don't have the rest of your code) appears to be that replacing the floating point with an integer caused the multiplication and division to be integer based, and not decimal based.  As a result, you now compute the wrong value.

Try type casting your uint32_t to a double and see if that clears it up.

Comment: the main problem here is overflow and not integer math, because 622080000 is already very big

Answer (score 1):

## The problem is due to overflow!

The original expression `(622.08E6 * vcxo_reg_val->hiv * vcxo_reg_val->n1)/temp_rfreq` (you have too many unnecessary parentheses though) is done in **`double` precision** because `622.08E6` is a `double` literal. That'll result in a floating-point value

However if you replace the literal with `622080000` then **the whole expression will be done in integer math** if all the variables are integer. But more importantly, integer math will overflow (at least much sooner than floating-point one)

Notice that `UINT32_MAX / 622080000.0 ≈ 6.9`. That means just multiply the constant by 7 and it'll overflow. However in the code you multiply 622080000 with 2 other values whose product may **well be above 6**. You should add the `ULL` suffix to do the math in `unsigned long long`

```
freq_xtal = (622080000ULL * vcxo_reg_val->hiv * vcxo_reg_val->n1)/temp_rfreq;
```

or change the variable to `uint64_t default_freq = 622080000ULL;`