# What is a scientific notation and why is double printed in scientific notation in Java?

Tags: java, scientific-notation

I use this code:

```
long elapsedTime = now - lastTime;
delta = ((double) elapsedTime) / 1000000000;
System.out.println(elapsedTime);
System.out.println(delta);
```

This is my output:

```
173290
1.7329E-4
```

This output gives me scientific notation, but I don't know what it is. Can you explain me? And why is double printed in scientific notation?

Comment: What's wrong with this output?

Comment: what is the strange thing which happens? looks normal to me.

Comment: BTW you can write `delta = elapsedTime / 1e9`;

Comment: What do you find strange? `1.7329E-4` is `1.7329 x 10 ^-4`, which is `0.00017329`

Comment: i expect 0.000173290

Comment: BTW, for ease of reading, consider `1_000_000_000`

Comment: oooooh. thank you i'm just now familiar with those E stuff. I'm just 13 so i didn't learn about that in school. but even tho i'm not really old i'm good at java trust me

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-to-print-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java

Comment: the problem now is... when i try to add 1*delta to my X of the play it stays at the same place

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation

Comment: @Joza100 The E part is scientific notation.

Comment: yeah i know, but when i say x += 1*delta x stays at 0

Comment: that's the new problem now,,,

Comment: What is `x` and where do you declare it? How do you check that it stays at 0. Maybe you should include the code for x in your question.

Comment: i have a rectangle, and i render it at x. it stays at the 0

Comment: public void tick(double delta) {
    x += 1*delta;
   }
   
   public void render(Graphics2D g) {
    g.drawRect((int)x, 0, 50, 50);
   }

Comment: `int` is a integer or whole number. If you have a fractional number then when you cast it to int, the fraction gets rounded off. Eg. `x += delta` gives you 0.00017 then you do `(int)x` you will be left with zero.

Comment: but it should move at time, as well i have to cast to int to use graphiccs2D

Comment: i found the problem..... it was moving to slow to be visible i increased to 10*delta and it works now

Comment: The displacement is too small. Start with `x = 0;` and `x+=delta;` the first time you call that, x will be less then 1 so `(int)x` will be zero. After you call that *a lot* x will be greater than one and your box will move. Another thing you can do is make a velocity. `double velocity = 1000` then `x+= delta*velocity`. That way you can change the value of velocity and move faster.

Comment: Yup thats what ive just done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you're seeing is [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

In Java, double is printed as scientific notation if the magnitude is less than `10^-3` or greater than `10^7`.

[Double#toString() javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double))

For a magnitude `m`:

- If `m` is greater than or equal to `10^-3` but less than `10^7`, then it is
  represented as the integer part of `m`, in decimal form with no leading
  zeroes, followed by `'.' ('\u002E')`, followed by one or more decimal
  digits representing the fractional part of `m`.
- If `m` is less than `10^-3` or greater than or equal to `10^7`, then it is
  represented in so-called "computerized scientific notation." Let `n` be
  the unique integer such that `10^n ≤ m < 10^n+1;` then let `a` be the
  mathematically exact quotient of `m` and `10^n` so that `1 ≤ a < 10`. The
  magnitude is then represented as the integer part of `a`, as a single
  decimal digit, followed by `'.' ('\u002E')`, followed by decimal digits
  representing the fractional part of `a`, followed by the letter `'E' ('\u0045')`, followed by a representation of `n` as a decimal integer,
  as produced by the method `Integer.toString(int)`.

Since your output of `1.7329E-4` has a magnitude of `10^-4`, it falls under the second category, per listed above.

Comment: thanks, now i get it. i'll sure have to remember it!! :D

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`. It's easier to read and less error-sensitive.

```
TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds(timeInSeconds)
```