# How can the suffix for numeric literals long int and long double both be l/L?

Tags: c++, syntax, literals

The suffix `l` and `L` for numeric literals `long int` and `long double` are the same. I don't understand how the compiler can know if I want my numeric literal to be a long int or a long double if they both share the same suffix. Why does this work?

I know I'm missing something completely obvious here.

Comment: See also the related questions: [Purpose of a “.f” appended to a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4828167/96780), [Why isn't “0f” treated as a floating point literal in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3961467/96780)

Comment: Thanks for the first link. I was messing around with trying to append an f suffix to an integer literal on my compiler and it was giving me syntax errors. This explains it well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A literal number needs to have a period or an exponent to be treated as a floating point literal constant. If it doesn't have any of these, it is treated as an integer literal constant.

Answer (score 0):

From C11 6.4.4.2/4:

> An unsuffixed **floating constant** has type double. If suffixed by the letter f or F, it has type float. If suffixed by the letter l or L, it has type long double.

A *floating constant* is defined by the grammar at the start of 6.4.4.2.  It must either contain `.` , so there is no ambiguity with integer constants which may not contain that.